# correct term for application on a website

Tags: web-services, web-applications, client-server

I am facing a terminology problem. A website takes some input from user, perform some analysis on server side and returns results to user. For example given some specific dates my bank website calculate financial report for that dates (balance without interest, interest rate, total balance etc.).
If I am making such a website what exactly I am making !! A "Web service" or a "Client-server system", a "web application" or "Software as a service" or something else?

Comment: Terminology like that comes from marketing, not developers. You can call it anything you want. In current times, everything is an app.

Comment: @kainaw yes you are right, for a developer it does't matter much. But I need the right term for academic purpose that's why I am looking for technically correct term.

Comment: It depends on the use. A web service implies that it is nothing more than a service supplied through a web page, not a full-blown application. A web application implies that it is a full application and not a simple service. A client-server system implies that you are developing both a client and a server, but it sounds like the client will be a web browser and the server will be the web server, neither of which you created.

Comment: You don't need it for academic purposes - your "academy" needs to grow up and realize there's no fixed term for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web service client is usually a program, not human. Web service does not have a GUI. A web application is used by human, thus must have GUI. The bank web site you talk about is a web application. However, it does not mean the same application cannot host web service and web application at the same time.

You can turn your web application into SaaS if

1. It is deployed in the cloud
2. It usually supports pay-as-you-go subscription model
3. It supports multi-tenancy.
4. It is able to scale up fast and efficiently, thus has elasticity
5. Usually it supports per-tenant customization or self-service signup.

As you can see, the most traits mentioned above are related to cloud computing.